# My project show before tableViewCell display label finished, CollectionViewCell display inner label in swit3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uitableview

How to control before TableViewCell label display, my CollectionViewCell label is displayed?
My CollectionViewCell is in TableViewCell.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 


         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CollectionViewCell

                let list = sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    cell.categoryTitle.text = list.package_name
                    cell.mainAssociatedURL.text = list.package_url
                    cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
                    cell.collectionView.reloadData()

                }

         return cell

    }
}
```

My CollectionViewCell is here,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 let list = sections[indexPath.row].packageTable[indexPath.row]

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! CollecitonViewCell



        AsyncImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString: list.poster_url) { (image, url) -> () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){

                cell.movieTitle.text = list.name
                if(url == StringResource().posterURL){
                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "mmcast_cover")
                }else{
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }

    return cell

}
```

I would like to show TableViewCell label display first and then go and display CollectionViewCell label and image.

Comment: Not Clear , kindly explain more if you can

Comment: @UsamaSadiq I edited and hope you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign delegate of collectionView inside tableviewcell.

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
cell.collectionView.delegate = nil
cell.collectionView.datasource = nil
```

**Change on delegate**

```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CollectionViewCell

                    let list = sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        cell.categoryTitle.text = list.package_name
                        cell.mainAssociatedURL.text = list.package_url
                        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
                        cell.collectionView.delegate = self
                        cell.collectionView.datasource = self
                        cell.collectionView.reloadData()

                    }

             return cell
```